# Combination Sum using recursion

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am new to data structure and I am trying this problem [Combination Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/description/)

I know this might be super basic stuff but I am learning recursion and not want to learn where I am doing wrong so that I can correct my thinking process.

Given an array of distinct integers candidates and a target integer target, return a list of all unique combinations of candidates where the chosen numbers sum to target. You may return the combinations in any order.

The same number may be chosen from candidates an unlimited number of times. Two combinations are unique if the
frequency
of at least one of the chosen numbers is different.

The test cases are generated such that the number of unique combinations that sum up to target is less than 150 combinations for the given input.

```
var combinationSum = function(candidates, target) {
    if(candidates.length == 0) return [[]]
    if(target == 0) return [[]]
    if(target<0) return []
    result = []
    for(let i=0; i<candidates.length; i++){
        let arr = [...candidates]
        // take the element
        let result1 = combinationSum([...candidates], target-candidates[i])
        // ignore the element
        result1.forEach((e)=>{e.push(candidates[i])})
        let result2 = combinationSum(arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i + 1)), target)
        result.push(...result1, ...result2)
    }
    return result
};
```

Right now, I am now working toward finding combination and not unique,
I am not able to comprehend why this is not working.

[image]

Comment: `[...result]` creates a **shallow** copy of `result` but you have arrays of arrays that you are mutating.  You might need a deep copy to avoid mutating existing arrays that you are trying to reuse.

Comment: @Wyck thank you for comment, I believe you meant this code 
result.push(...result1, ...result2). I can not see why sending array elements inside result would be an issue here, can you please help me in this

Comment: You want a deep copy.  So `structuredClone(foo)` not `[...foo]`.  You may want to `push( ...structuredClone(result1), ...structuredClone(result2))`.  But there are more problems.  I don't think mutating with push is smart here at all.  Also, you need to watch out for empty arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues:

- The condition `candidates.length == 0` does not guarantee you have found a solution, so returning `[[]]` is premature. You should *first* check if the target was reached. If not, only then check whether you have no more candidates, and if that is so, then you *didn't* find a solution, and should return `[]`.

  This bug is why some entries in your result do not sum up to the target value.
- You've defined your `result` variable implicitly as a *global* variable, which will bring havoc: now the recursive call will *reset* the array that the caller wants to build up, and will *populate* it with different entries. You should define `result` as a *local* variable with `const` (or `let`).

  This bug also causes some entries in your result to not sum up to the target value.
- The `for` loop will make that you visit all combinations in all their orders, but that means you will visit duplicate combinations. For example, [1,2,3] and [3,2,1] are the same combination according to the definition of "unique" given in the question. To avoid such duplicates, make sure that you only pick candidate values from the part of the array that starts at the place where you made your last pick. This really means you can skip the `for` loop and only do that logic for `i` equal to 0.

Not a problem, but the code comment `// ignore the element` is placed at the wrong spot. It should be placed one line further.

So by changing as little as possible, your code can be corrected to this:

```
var combinationSum = function(candidates, target) {
    if (target == 0) return [[]];
    if (candidates.length == 0) return []; // Moved here, and returning no solution.
    if (target < 0) return [];
    const result = []; // This should not be a global variable
    // Removed loop: Don't allow values to be taken in any order.
    let i = 0;
    let arr = [...candidates]
    // take the element
    let result1 = combinationSum([...candidates], target-candidates[i])
    result1.forEach((e)=>{e.push(candidates[i])})
    // ignore the element (this comment appeared at the wrong line)
    let result2 = combinationSum(arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i + 1)), target)
    result.push(...result1, ...result2)
    return result
};
```

Of course, you could clean up the code a bit, as now you don't need `i`; the `slice` can be simplified; the `result` variable is not really needed as you can return the concatenation of `result1` and `result2` immediately; `arr` is not needed as you can slice from `candidates` directly when you pass the sliced argument to the recursive call; ...etc.

Here is a version after some "cleanup":

```
var combinationSum = function(candidates, target) {
    if (target == 0) return [[]];
    if (candidates.length == 0 || target < 0) return [];
    const [first, ...rest] = candidates;
    // take the element
    const resultTake = combinationSum(candidates, target - first);
    resultTake.forEach((e) => e.push(first));
    return [
        ...resultTake, 
        // ignore the element
        ...combinationSum(rest, target)
    ];
};
```